# How do I use button action events to call other classes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, actionlistener

I am trying to create a GUI program using JFrame that allows me to call to call other classes when a button is clicked in the main class of another class.  I used JPanel to create the GUI panel so I could organize the buttons and such, so not all parts of the panel are in the same class.  I am having a hard time figuring out a way to use a button click in one class to have the main method call other classes to perform their actions.  I tried sending an int value to a mutator and accessor  and then get the int from that, but it doesn't set the global variable.  Is it a problem of sequence?  Please help.

Here is a small piece of the code in case I was not being very clear(I am sure I wasn't):
This is the class with the main method in it:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GUI extends JFrame{

private hPanel hp;
private mPanel mp;

public GUI(){
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setTitle("GUI");

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
hp = new hPanel();
mp = new mPanel();
add(hp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(mp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
pack();
setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[]args){
mPanel MP = new mPanel();
pPanel PP = new pPanel();
int buttIn = MP.getbuttonIndicator();


if (MP.getbuttonIndicator()==1){
PP.tester1();
}
else if (MP.getbuttonIndicator()==2){
PP.tester2();
}
else if (MP.getbuttonIndicator()==3){
PP.tester3();
}
else if (MP.getbuttonIndicator()==4){
PP.tester4();
}
else if (MP.getbuttonIndicator()==5){
PP.tester5();
}
else if (MP.getbuttonIndicator()==6){
PP.tester6();
}
new Grade();

}
}
```

I want to use the buttons in this actionListener to initiate the calls from the main to other classes.  This actionListener is in another class from the main method:

```
private class JButtonListener implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
if (e.getSource()==button1){
buttonIndicator = 1;
setbuttonIndicator(buttonIndicator);
}
if (e.getSource()==button2){
buttonIndicator = 2;
setbuttonIndicator(buttonIndicator);
}
if (e.getSource()==button3){
buttonIndicator = 3;
setbuttonIndicator(buttonIndicator);
}
if (e.getSource()==button4){
buttonIndicator = 4;
setbuttonIndicator(buttonIndicator);
}
if (e.getSource()==button5){
buttonIndicator = 5;
setbuttonIndicator(buttonIndicator);
}
if (e.getSource()==button6){
buttonIndicator = 6;
setbuttonIndicator(buttonIndicator);
}

}
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider taking a look at [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) which provides you the means to specify a self-contained unit of work for a specific action, which can then be applied to a `JButton`.  This would allow you to encapsulate the required references and take appropriate action when the button is triggered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is kind of unclear, I mean this is as simple as the following if I think I understand what you're asking.

```
if (e.getSource() == btn) {
Car c = new Car();
c.methodName(parameters);
}
```

This is of course assuming Car is a class in your project.

Comment: the actionListener is in a class that does not have the main method, can I do that from outside the main method?  I could just pass a value through like Car c = new Car(1); correct?

Comment: Yes as long as passing a `1` through the constructor of your Class satisfies the "construction" if it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it was such an easy and simple answer, but it was the missing piece I was looking for for days.  You saved my life!!!!